# Does dependency exist if A is only used in a method of B?

Tags: data-modeling, uml

I have a class **Idea** and class **Generator**

In Generator's **run()** method, a list of **Idea** will be **constructed** and returned as return value of run()

I only know that if Generator has a member which is a list of **Idea**, their dependency relationship will exist certainly. But how about the situation I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at dependencies, ask yourself what would happen if you didn't have that particular class. If it wouldn't run/compile, then there is a dependency. So yes, Generator has a dependency on Idea.

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies are displayed at classifier level in the class diagram. I mean that if two methods call each other then there is a dependency. You have different kinds of dependencies which are displayed with a dependency link and a stereotype such as << call >> etc..

Below is an example:
[image]
<sub>(source: [forum-omondo.com](http://www.forum-omondo.com/documentation_eclipseuml_2008/dependencies_view.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The situation you are describing is a *Usage* dependency following the *create* stereotype. It is indeed a classic example of dependency, as noted here:

[Dependency relationships in UML](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cdepend.html)